# Pushing uncommited files to github based on the date it was created

Tags: git, eclipse, github

So, I created a bunch of java files on eclipse and didn't realise to commit it. So, the files are created on different days and I want to push it based on the day It got created. Is this possible without fake committing (changing the date to previous date and committing) it?

Comment: So do you want to create a commit with an earlier date, and put it before later already existing commits? what exactly do you want to achieve from a Git history perspective?

Comment: "*Is this possible without fake committing (changing the date to previous date and committing) it?*" Nop, no way.

Comment: @dunni i want it to appear on github that I worked on that day and show that I was active

Comment: @psycho11 I'm quite sure you cannot do that. Just deleted my answer, since it was irrelevant: I had missed the key part of your question about no fake committing.

Comment: Git doesn't push *files*. Git pushes *commits*. If you want to push something, it must be a commit.